# How can i solve Image into android app from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mySql database with one table. That table contain Texts,Ints and 1 Blob(images) . I didn't use PHP and JSON. I would use the pictures in my app but i can't handle Blob. How  can i  solve that?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2/dbase","root","root");

                String select="SELECT * FROM animals WHERE name like '%" + a_name + "%';" ;
                PreparedStatement state=con.prepareStatement(select);

          ResultSet rs=state.executeQuery();
          .
          .
          .
          .
          .
           Blob kep = rs.getBlob("imgs");
```

how to continue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what format is the image stored in the table?  If it's a bitmap, then this should work for you:

```
byte[] kepBytes = kep.getBytes(0, kep.length());
Bitmap kepBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(kepBytes, 0, kepBytes.length);
```

**EDIT**: also note that if `a_name` is input by the user, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.  A parameterized query would be a better approach:

```
String select="SELECT * FROM animals WHERE name LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement state=con.prepareStatement(select);
state.setString(1, "%" + a_name + "%");
ResultSet rs=state.executeQuery();
```

Comment: The images format LONGBLOB ...and how can i convert to image that? i would like save to storage (etc external storage)

Comment: Before it was inserted into the table, in what format was the image encoded?  And are you planning to display or manipulate the image at all after the query is run, or are you just looking to save it directly to storage?

Comment: i want to use this in ListView. I thought ,i save imgae before use.What do you think?Is it not important?

I do not want to manipulate images

Comment: If you're displaying multiple images in the `ListView`, then you'll likely benefit from implementing a memory/disk caching library, as you'll probably run into memory and performance issues pretty quickly.  Several of the popular ones are designed to work solely with images over the network, but some will work with local images. See [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/), [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).  The code in my answer, however, gets you to the point that you have a displayable image.

Comment: Hmm..hmmm ..Glide likeable ... but it seem complicated for me and i ahve 3 day, need a fast solve :/ what do you think? should you , i try Glade?

Comment: i never used like this yet.

Comment: These libraries each have their strengths, so the best one for your project depends on its particular requirements, but since three days is a tight deadline even for someone who routinely implements this kind of functionality, it might be best to just go with the one that looks the easiest to understand and implement at this point.

Comment: Well , i thank your help and if i finish , i will feedback for you

Comment: Will look forward to it.  Good luck. ^^

Comment: Good morning! :) ImageSaves is succeeded! I use the InternalStorage. Now my problem, how can i use this pictures in ListView? It was early my solve for Strings but now i would like use image too.

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I'm in a different timezone.  Getting your images into the ListView and wiring it together with caching will require work in an adapter.  Consider opening a new question on StackOverflow for this, because it can get pretty complicated.

Comment: I think i will make a CustomAdapter, but now i'm flu -.-"